# how call controller through ajax and get data from into fields of modal from database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

*I am beginner so spare me. I am using code igniter. I have a table and in this table I have a button edit. When the edit button is clicked it shows a pop up modal. Main purpose of this is to update the specific row data like name password etc. That why i called modal pop up which displays a form where i want to show specific record so that i can edit that record and click update which will update the record. I just want to show the specific record as each row have its own edit button. i can change the record through php. but need to display it. 
**This is my modal popup and that table where the data from database is displayed.**
Someone please tell what is the code to do this work. **I want full ajax code so anyone who have a kind heart please write that code so that i can enter into my website. Please help. this is all i know and i have shared**
Code:

```
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel2">
                         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">

                                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel1">Update Current User</h4>
                                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                                                <div class="card">
                                                <div class="card-header">
                                                    End User Info
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="card-body">
                                <form action="<?php echo base_url()."User_area/add_new_subusers"?>" method="post" id="newuserform" class="form-horizontal">
                                    <div class="form-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                    <label class="control-label text-right col-md-5">First Name:</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subufname" value="" name="subufname" placeholder="Enter First Name"></input>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                    <label class="control-label text-right col-md-5">Last Name:</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subulname" id="subulname" value="" placeholder="Enter Last Name"></input>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                    <label class="control-label text-right col-md-5">Email:</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subuemail" name="subuemail" value="" placeholder="Enter Email"></input>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--/span-->
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                    <label class="control-label text-right col-md-5">Password:</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subupass" id="subupass" placeholder="New Password"></input>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--/span-->
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group row">
                                                    <label class="control-label text-right col-md-5">Confirm Password:</label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-7">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subuconfirmpass" placeholder="Confirm New Password"></input>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--/span-->

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                                </div>
                                                </div>



                               </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <input type="submit" id="createnewuser" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                </div></div>
                <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">

                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="table-responsive m-t-40">
                                    <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                                        <thead style="background: #37a000; color: #fff;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Name</th>
                                                <th>Email/Username</th>
                                                <th>Password</th>

                                                <th>User Role</th>
                                                <th>Email Notification</th>
                                                <th>Client Access</th>
                                                <th>Action</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
 <!-- ******************************Displaying Data*************************************************************** -->
                                        <tbody>

<?php
foreach($profle as $row):  ?>
        <tr>   
         <td><?echo $row['fname']?></td>
         <td><?echo $row['email']?></td>
         <td><?echo $row['password']?></td>
         <td><?echo $row['user_role']?></td>
         <td>***</td>
         <td>***</td>
         <td><a class="btn btn-success" style="color:white;background-color:green;padding:0px 2px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">edit</a></td>
       </tr>
       <?php  endforeach; ?>

</tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple ajax for you . Hope it can help you

ajax script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#popup-button").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var profle_id =$(this).children().val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "HERE FILE CONTROLLER",
                type : 'get',
                data: "id="+profle_id,
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(result){ // result ='{ "fname":"John", "email":"abc@gmail", "password":"New York" , "user_role":"York" }';
                    $('#subufname').val(result['name']);
                    $('#subulname').val(result['email']);
                    $('#subuemail').val(result['password']);
                    $('#subupass').val(result['user_role']);

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

edit table :

```
<tr>
                        <td><?echo $row['fname']?></td>
                        <td><?echo $row['email']?></td>
                        <td><?echo $row['password']?></td>
                        <td><?echo $row['user_role']?></td>
                        <td>***</td>
                        <td>***</td>
                        <td><a class="btn btn-success" style="color:white;background-color:green;padding:0px 2px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2" id = "popup-button">edit<input type="hidden" value ="$row['id']" ></a></td>

                    </tr>
```

Comment: Do `<?echo $row['fname']?>` need to change `<?= $row['fname']?>` or `<?php echo $row['fname']?>`  ?

Comment: PHP also allows for short open tag <? (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).

Comment: nice, let me check :D

Comment: I can't use `<?echo ?>` tag :) Do you get mistakes? I just use `<?= ?>` for the `short_open_tag`

Comment: i usually use <?php ?> tag.  You try to check short_open_tag with the phpinfo() statement

Comment: Look at your answer~  `<td><?echo $row['fname']?></td>`. It's wrong tag or I'm wrong?

Comment: :)) i copy from your code, i only add id for a tag and input tag

Comment: Copy from me? xD. I don't post this question.
@user3397832 More information. In the controller, response the data like this `echo json_encode($data)` and in the ajax success `JSON.parse(result)`;

Comment: sorry , I forget @user3397832 :) . I set "dataType : 'json'" , you no need JSON.parse(result)

Comment: the above code no errors.i am using code igniter platform. i just want to get data from data base into the modal popup